# strange character \u2b00b in javascript code

Tags: javascript

A for loop didn't compile on some code we were working on. It looks innocuous enough :

```
for (i in col) {

}
```

Webstorm didn't like it, and extJS didn't like it. On first inspection there was nothing wrong with it, but when we put it in JSFiddle it comes up with an error

http://jsfiddle.net/oliverwatkins/tn2dmnou/

These strange invisible **\u2b00b** characters got into the code.

what is it? Google gives back nothing useful. And how did it get there?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b00b/index.htm seems wrong

Comment: Also, that fiddle is pretty useless...

Comment: don't you get two red circles over the end of a for loop?

Comment: yes, thank you , i am aware I can just delete the character. But I am questioning what it was, how it got there..

Comment: I'm not sure that anybody can possibly tell you how some random garbage character got into your source file.